# VideoView is not viewing when visibility is set to visible

Tags: android, video, android-videoview

I have created a video playlist which displays the names of the video files stored in sd card. By default the visibility of the video view is "gone". I want the videoview to become visible and play the video once I select the video from the playlist. But unable to do that.

Here is my code:

VideoFragment.java

```
public class VideoFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener, OnCompletionListener {

    ListView list;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter ;
    VideoListAdapter listAdapter;
    ArrayList<String> listTest;
     ArrayList<String> listSoundNames;
    ImageButton play,stop,back,next;
    String songpath,song,title;
    int index,current_position;
    File[] listFile;
    SharedPreferences sharedPref;
    MediaPlayer mp,mp2;
    ActionBar bar;
    private Boolean state=false;
    private static int save = -1;
    int count=0;
    private static final String TAG = VideoFragment.class.getSimpleName();
    //private Context _context = this;
    public static int selected_item=-1;
    VideoView video;
    MediaController controller;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_games, container, false);


        //controller = new MediaController(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
            video = (VideoView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.video1);
            //video.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            list = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
            //list.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
            list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE); 

           // _context=this;

            listTest = new ArrayList<String>( );
            listSoundNames=new ArrayList<String>();

            play = (ImageButton)rootView.findViewById(R.id.play);
            back = (ImageButton)rootView.findViewById(R.id.prev);
            next = (ImageButton)rootView.findViewById(R.id.next);

            //adding listeners
            play.setOnClickListener(this);
            back.setOnClickListener(this);
            next.setOnClickListener(this);


            //action bar controls
            bar = getActivity().getActionBar();
            bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#DF0174")));
            //bar.setIcon(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent))); 



            EditText editText = new EditText(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
            getActivity().getActionBar().setCustomView(editText);

            Scanner("/sdcard/");//storage path


            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            /////////////////////////////////////*Adding listener to songs*//////////////////////////////////////////////////
            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            if(listTest.size() != 0)
            {

                listAdapter=new VideoListAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),listSoundNames);
                list.setAdapter(listAdapter);

                list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
                {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
                {

                    //////////////////changing list item background on click///////////////////


                    //list.setSelection(position);
                    //view.setSelected(true);
                    ///////////////////PROBLEM/////////////

                    for(int a = 0; a < parent.getChildCount(); a++)
                    {
                        list.clearChoices();
                        parent.getChildAt(a).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);


                    }

                    selected_item=position;
                   // view.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);


                    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                    //accessing song path

                    list.setItemChecked(position, true);
                    list.setSelection(position);

                    //accessing the song name
                    String name = (String) ((TextView) view).getText();
                    title = name;
                    //bar.setTitle(title);
                    //Log.e(TAG, name);

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    try{
                        //video.setMediaController(controller); 


                        video.setVideoPath(listTest.get(position));//source
                        video.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
                        video.requestFocus();

                        video.start();
                        index = position;
                        play.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);
                        }
                    catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}



                }


                });




                }
            return rootView;
            }






     private void Scanner(String path) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            {
                try 
                {
                        File fl = new File(path);
                        File[] listOfFiles = fl.listFiles();              

                        for (File listOfFile : listOfFiles)
                         {
                            String s = listOfFile.getName();

                            if(s.endsWith(".mp4"))
                            {

                            songpath = listOfFile.getPath();
                            listTest.add(songpath);//adding song names to list
                            //listTest.toString().replaceFirst(songpath, s);



                            // store file name in listSoundNames
                            int pos = s.lastIndexOf(".");
                            if (pos > 0)
                            {
                                song = s.substring(0, pos);
                            }
                            listSoundNames.add(song);

                            }


                            /////////////////////////////////
                            File f = new File(path+s+"/");
                            if (f.exists() && f.isDirectory()) {
                            Scanner(path+s+"/");
                            }
                            ////////////////////////////////


                        }



                }
            catch (Exception e) { }
            }

            }







    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        if (v.equals(play))
        {
            if(mp.isPlaying())
            {
                mp.pause();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "paused", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //change in button image//
                play.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);

            }
            else
            {
                mp.start();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //change in button image//
                play.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);
                //
            }
        }


            if (v.equals(back))
            {
                mp.stop();
                mp.reset();
                //bar.setTitle(song);

                if(index!=0)
                {
                index = index -1;
                selected_item=index;
                listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();//shifting the highlight to the song played
                }
                else
                {
                    index = (list.getAdapter().getCount()-1)-1;
                    selected_item=index;
                    listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }

                Uri uri = Uri.parse(listTest.get(index).toString());//getting the path of next song
                try {


                    mp.setDataSource(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), uri);//setting new data source 


                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (SecurityException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();///PROBLEM:MOVING HERE AFTER CLICKING NEXT BUTTON
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                try {
                    mp.prepare();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }        
                mp.start();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), ""+uri, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }


            if (v.equals(next))
            {

                mp.stop();
                mp.reset();
                index = index +1;

                selected_item=index;
                listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                //Toast.makeText(MP3.this, ""+selected_item, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(listTest.get(index).toString());//getting the path of next song

                try {


                    mp.setDataSource(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), uri);//setting new data source 


                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (SecurityException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();///PROBLEM:MOVING HERE AFTER CLICKING NEXT BUTTON
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                try {
                    mp.prepare();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }        
                mp.start();//PROBLEM: NOT PLAYING
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), ""+uri, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }


    }






    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        play.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
    }
}
```

fragment_movies.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#CECEF6"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="398dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.44"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:choiceMode="none"
            android:scrollingCache="false" >
        </ListView>  

        <VideoView

        android:id="@+id/video1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone"/>




    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="63dp" >
           <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:padding="2dp" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/prev"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:src="@drawable/prev" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="15dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 

                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/play"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:src="@drawable/play" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="15dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 

                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/next"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:src="@drawable/next" />
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**UPDATE:** *Here is the logcat*

```
10-14 18:57:45.311: W/System.err(7545): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-14 18:57:45.311: W/System.err(7545):     at info.androidhive.tabsswipe.VideoFragment$1.onItemClick(VideoFragment.java:150)
10-14 18:57:45.312: W/System.err(7545):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
10-14 18:57:45.312: W/System.err(7545):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1128)
10-14 18:57:45.312: W/System.err(7545):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2815)
10-14 18:57:45.312: W/System.err(7545):     at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3574)
10-14 18:57:45.312: W/System.err(7545):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
10-14 18:57:45.312: W/System.err(7545):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
10-14 18:57:45.312: W/System.err(7545):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
10-14 18:57:45.312: W/System.err(7545):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
10-14 18:57:45.313: W/System.err(7545):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-14 18:57:45.313: W/System.err(7545):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-14 18:57:45.313: W/System.err(7545):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
10-14 18:57:45.313: W/System.err(7545):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
10-14 18:57:45.313: W/System.err(7545):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: You should use class View instead of using view.VISIBLE, use View.VISIBLE.

Comment: Problem still persists.

Comment: I would like to add that the play button image even doesn't change when using the code written(i.e. for the video view) just before it, but the button image changes on click if that part of code is not used. Strange thing.

Answer (score -2):

Change `video.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE)`; to `video.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`

Comment: This fixed your issue?